# Cargar archivos excel de manera óptima con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy cargando un archivo excel que pesa cerca de 50MB, utilizo pandas y la función read_excel, pero tarda demaciado entre 3 y 5 minutos y también utilice open pero pasa lo mismo, ¿hay alguna librería para optimizar el tiempo de carga?

```
import pandas

file = pd.read_excel('archivo.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
df
```

Comment: He leído sobre stackoverflow que leer un csv esta mas rápido

Comment: Tienes razón @Marine1 la desventaja es que pesa 3 veces más y necesitaria pasar el archivo excel a csv antes de manipularlo.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que un .xlsx es básicamente un xml comprimido, de hecho si cambias la extensión a .zip lo podrás abrir como tal. Pandas en este caso debe descomprimir y procesar completamente un xml, no es un proceso sencillo justamente. Esto te lo comento, por que la idea del CSV no es descabellada, seguramente el xlsx descomprimido "pese" mucho más que un CSV plano.

Answer (score 3):

A continuación les voy a detallar de manera mas detallada la configuración de excel hacia Python.

1) Como primero que vamos a hacer para seguir este tutorial es descargar este documento sobre el cual me voy a basar en los siguientes pasos; después de que te enseñe a manipular cierta información, puedes intentar lo mismo con algún otro documento de tu propiedad ejecutamos los siguientes comandos.

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('modificar_excel.xlsx')
>>> doc.get_sheet_names()
[u'Hoja1', u'Hoja2', u'Hoja3']
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) pues una ver abrimos en el exel nos ponemos lo siguientes comandos "Hoja1", entonces vamos a decirle a python que en una variable hoja, nos cargue toda la información relacionada a ella, de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> hoja = doc.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
```

3)Ahora vamos a suponer que deseamos cambiar el valor 40 de la celda B2 de nuestra hoja, por un 99, solo tendríamos que hacer lo siguiente:

```
>>> hoja['B2'] = 99
```

De esta manera podemos acceder a la celda y cambiar su valor, estos pueden ser formateados según sea el caso, es decir, que podemos insertar fechas, flotantes, cadenas e incluso formulas.
Vamos a intentar cambiar el valor 99 por una formula sencilla:

```
hoja['B2'] = "=SUM(1, 1)"
>>> hoja['B2'].value
u'=SUM(1, 1)'
```

4) Guardamos todos los cambios,sin embarco Recuerden que el argumento del método `save()`, tiene que llevar el mismo nombre de nuestro archivo xlsx, si le cambiamos el nombre, OpenPyxl nos va crear un nuevo documento .

```
>>> doc.save("modificar_excel.xlsx")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5) Ahora vamos a ver otra interesante función que nos permite esta librería...Supongamos que deseamos agregar nueva información al final de nuestra tabla, por ejemplo "Junio, 99, 100"; lo hariamos de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> hoja.append(["Junio",99,100])
>>> hoja['A7'].value
u'Junio'
>>> hoja['B7'].value
99
>>> hoja['C7'].value
100
```

Podemos notar, que haciendo uso del método append() de la instancia de nuestra hoja, nos permite agregar una fila nueva. Este método recibe como parámetro un dato de tipo lista que debe contener la información que deseamos insertar de izquierda a derecha (siempre en ese orden).

6) Porultimo paso para complementar de la mejor manera este tutorial, voy a mostrarles como crear una gráfica de área (Es posible crear casi todas las gráficas disponibles por excel mediante OpenPyxl).

Primero vamos a importar lo siguiente:

```
>>> from openpyxl.chart import (AreaChart, Reference, Series)
```

7) Necesitamos de esas 3 clases para poder crear nuestra gráfica, también es posible crear una gráfica 3D, solo debemos cambiar AreaChart por AreaChart3d.
Ahora debemos configurar la información de nuestra grafica, como el estilo y los distintos titulos que se muestran en el eje X, Y.

```
>>> grafica = AreaChart()
>>> grafica.title = "Grafica de Area"
>>> grafica.style = 13
>>> grafica.x_axis.title = "Periodo"
>>> grafica.y_axis.title = "Utilidades"
```

8) Después vamos a configurar las referencias que mostraran la información de los meses:

```
periodo = Reference(hoja, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
```

Si analizamos nuestra hoja de calculo, tenemos que toda la columna A hace referencia a la información del periodo y es por ello que dentro del constructor del objeto Referencia, como primer argumento le indicamos la hoja que tenemos cargada, la columna mínima (es decir A) y posteriormente el rango de información de dicha columna 2-7.

Ahora es el turno de hacer lo mismo, pero a los valores de nuestros periodos

```
>>> utilidades = Reference(hoja, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=7)
```

9) Por ultimo que nos queda por hacer es agregar la información a nuestra instancia de AreaChart la cual llamamos grafica y agregar ese objeto a nuestra hoja de calculo para después guardar el documento escribimos el siguiente comando.

```
>>> grafica.add_data(utilidades, titles_from_data=True)
>>> grafica.set_categories(periodo)
>>> hoja.add_chart(grafica, "A10")
>>> doc.save("modificar_excel.xlsx")
```

Si abrimos nuestro archivo en Microsoft Excel, vamos a encontrarnos con el resultado esperado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que este contenido haya sido de su agrado.

Answer (score 1):

haciéndolo de la siguiente manera ganarás un poco de velocidad (no mucha) y en caso de error el archivo se cerrara de todos modos, puedes obtener mas información en la documentación de pandas.

```
with pd.Excelfile(archivo, opciones) as excel:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel, opciones)
```